# Variable "i" not displaying in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I am trying to do some for loop practice and apply the blue color style to all "listing" class with a click event. In addition to that, i also wanted to print the value of "i" in every loop. Can anyone point out what im missing in the code please. Thank you
Here is my code:

```js
function changeClass(){
  
   for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
      var list =  document.getElementsByClassName("listing")[i];
      list.style.color = "blue";
      var values = document.getElementsByClassName("value");
      document.write(i);
   }
}

document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", changeClass);
```

```html
<ul id="groupList">
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li class="value"></li>
</ul>
<button id="change">change listing</button>
```

Comment: you want i value in every loop like 0,1,2 ?

Comment: What are you planning to do with `values`, the list of elements with the class `value`?

Comment: yes sir to display after the list

Comment: just wanted to display the i value for every loop

Comment: listing on the top and 
0<br/>
1<br/>
2<br/>
below

Comment: the page will be replaced with a `0` when `document.write(i);` executed the first time .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used `document.write()` function it may be override document HTML content you can use `console.log()` method for debugging variable. Also take element reference in one variable so it will make some faster execution. Change `class="value"` to `id="value"` because it only one element so identifier is good instead of class. Class refer to multiple element but id refer to only one element.

```js
function changeClass(){
   var dom=document.getElementsByClassName("listing");
   var all_index=[]
   for (i=0;i<dom.length;i++) {
      var list =  dom[i];
      list.style.color = "blue";
      all_index.push(i);
      
   }
   document.getElementById("value").innerHTML=all_index.join(",");
      
}

document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", changeClass);
```

```html
<ul id="groupList">
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li id="value"></li>
</ul>
<button id="change">change listing</button>
```

Comment: Please follow standard international English in your posts. Sentences are ended with a period (full stop). The first word in sentences is capitalized.

Comment: What do you think the `var values` line is doing, and why did you leave it in your solution?

Comment: Calm down. You got 28 points for a post which is both poorly written, and also did not make the obvious inference that the OP wanted to write out `i` into the `value` element and show him how to do that.

Comment: @torazaburo, check snippet of OP, might be OP need it... I know it useless in our perspective but OP might be use else where.

Comment: thank you. how do you display them numbers in the page?

Comment: @jerz, I have modified answer.. please check it.

Comment: @torazaburo, thanks for your suggestions.. In SO english is not matter but good solution always matter :).. obvious good English need :)

Comment: Thank you sir. I haven't used this before "[ ]" as a value but this works and big help. I am learning

Comment: @jerz, `[]` is short tag for `new Array()`, and `{}` is short tag for `new Object()`, if you like my answer then mark as correct and give up vote also

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a listener to invoke chageClass function

```
document.getElementById("change").addEventListener('click',changeClass,true);
```

***Here i am going to indicate the reason of the problem in for loop :***

```
inside your for loop when i==0;
```

**document.write(i)** will **elimenate** all the elements in your document and will print 0 in you document if everything is ok.

```
when i==1 in for loop :
```

the following line will become invalid because there will be no element holding the class "listing" .All other elements are eliminated from document .Now it will eliminate `"0"` form document and print `"1"` in document.and it will go on and on as long as the for loop goes on .

```
var list =  document.getElementsByClassName("listing")[i];
```

use **document.body.innerHTML** instead if you want to print in document:

```
   function changeClass(){

   for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
      var list =  document.getElementsByClassName("listing")[i];

      list.style.color = "blue";
      var values = document.getElementsByClassName("value");
     document.body.innerHTML+='<br>'+i+'<br>';
   }

}
  document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click',changeClass,true);
```