# why not the element's textnode gets logged in the console of firefox devtool

Tags: javascript

i answered to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586088/variable-i-not-displaying-in-javascript-for-loop/39586273#39586273) earlier today. i understand that whole document is rewritten in each loop inside for loop.There will be no element in the dom tree.But i have a simple question in mind that inside i made a console.log() which will log out the inner text of each element.As all the code is synchronous the TEXT of first list element should get printed as `document.write(i)` is below in sequence? or it is fast enough for my eye to miss?

```
<html>
<body>
<ul id="groupList">
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li id="value"></li>
</ul>
<button id="change">change listing</button>
<script>
function changeClass(){
   var list =  document.querySelectorAll(".listing");
   for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
      console.log(list[i].innerHTML);

      list[i].style.color = "blue";

      document.write(i);
   }

}
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click',changeClass,true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not sure what your question is..the above code is printing 3 "First" in console and "012" in DOM, which is as expected.

Comment: in my firefox devtool ....i dont see the textnodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As all the code is synchronous the TEXT of first list element should get printed as `document.write(i)` is below in sequence? or it is fast enough for my eye to miss?

The first call to `document.write` wipes out the entire document. What happens at that point appears to be browser-dependent (and very interesting!).

In Chrome, once I press the button I see "First" three times in the console and `012` in the document (and I do when I try it).

In Firefox, pressing the button shows me "First" **once** in the console, and `012` in the document.

In IE, pressing the button shows me "First" **once** in the console and only `0` in the document.

Each makes sense to me in a different way:

- `querySelectorAll` returns a *disconnected* collection of elements. That means they remain in the collection even after they've been removed from the document (unlike, say, `getElementsByTagName`, which is live).
- My guess is Chrome treats the console as part of the browser. It's happy to keep looping through the disconnected elements and output them to that one console.
- My guess is Firefox treats the console as document-specific. So the `console` we're writing to no longer exists after the first `document.write`.
- My guess is IE throws an exception or just terminates the script (I was experimenting and saw it throw an Access Denied once but not every time) when the document has been destroyed.

Bottom-line: If you destroy the entire document, perhaps don't be too surprised to find odd results when you try to keep using that document's resources.

Live copy:

```js
function changeClass(){
   var list =  document.querySelectorAll(".listing");
   for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
      console.log(list[i].innerHTML);

      list[i].style.color = "blue";

      document.write(i);
   }

}
document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click',changeClass,true);
```

```html
(Look in the console, too, I didn't use the in-snippet console because <code>document.write</code> will blow it away.)
<ul id="groupList">
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li class="listing">First</li>
<li id="value"></li>
</ul>
<button id="change">change listing</button>
```

---

Side note: `true` as the third argument to `addEventListener` is **extremely** rare: It tells `addEventListener` to hook up the handler to the *capturing* phase rather than the *bubbling* phase. Overwhelmingly, the normal practice is to hook up handlers in the bubbling phase (`false` as the third argument, or on modern browsers, no third argument at all).

Side note 2: The code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. `i` is never declared anywhere.

Comment: didn't show "first" three time in the console...that's what i am wondering about :|

Comment: it shows in chrome but not in firefox...i was testing on firefox

Comment: @AL-zami: This is *very* interesting. And apologies, I may have just removed the explanation you liked when adding in a new one. Which is speculative, it may be more appropraite for me to delete the answer.

Comment: It seems `document.write` replaces the window on Firefox, but that code still runs in the old one, and that's why `console.log` stops working. But `document.defaultView.console.log(list[i].innerHTML)` works.

Comment: it is a good answer...you can add more to it if seems fit  .. :)

Comment: @oriol it prints "FIRST" only two times in my firefox console ,not three times

Comment: `window.console.log` also works. I guess this is due to the difference between a Window and a WindowProxy objects.

Comment: @Oriol: Fascinating (both comments)!

Comment: my head is spinning ..... now i have to establish two different sets of understanding for two different browsers !

Comment: @AL-zami: At least. :-) Nothing new there, it's the nature of web dev. But this is definitely an edge case you should normally be safe from.